# Display Backslash in html text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to display text with backslashes in my textbox. \t places a tab(4 spaces) in the text box like

> **C:     able** instead of **C:\table**

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
<div>
    <input style="margin-top: 20px;" type="button" id='btn' value="Set new value" />
</div>

$('#btn').on('click', function () {
     var testval = 'C:\table';
    $('#input').val(testval);
});
```

Is there a way to escape this backslah and display the path completely?

Comment: Escape the `\ ` with a `\ `: `C:\\table`

Comment: testval = testval.replace("\\","\\\\") does not solve the purpose and also the testval is a dynamic data and not a static text. So need a generic function to replace/escape it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to escape the back slash, otherwise it's interpreted as an tab:

```
"C:\\table"
```

Comment: Darn it :D you beat me to it! I was typing this answer when I saw an answer had been added. This is correct, since a single backslash will trigger an escape sequence.

Comment: How do you escape the backslash. regex or replace does not work for what i have tried :(

Comment: It's quite simple! If you want to use a \ in a string write instead \\ (double back slash). The first back slash escapes the second. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put two backslaces: instead of 'C:\table' -> use 'C:\table'

this works for all languages( that's how you escape special characters )

Answer (score 0):

Escape the backslash as : `var testval = 'C:\\table';` or try using

```
var testval = 'C:\table';
JSON.stringify(testval);
```

Comment: :) great...but how to avoid the doublequotes around it :(

Comment: When I use stringify it doesnt work for other strings like 'C:\good' or any things that doesnt have \t, \n, etc